# Вынести события кнопок и полей в отдельный файл WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, события

У меня в приложении имеется много текстбоксов и кнопок. На каждый текстбокс по одному событию. Снизу предоставляю пример. Таких событий около 30. Хочется вынести эти события в отдельный файл, чтобы не засорять основной файл формы.

```
private void AuthorBook_TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    AuthorBook_TextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    AuthorBook_TextBox.ToolTip = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Учить MVVM, привязки данных (`Binding`) и команды (`ICommand`). В WPF обработчиками событий в таких случаях никто не пользуется.

С другой стороны, возможно проблема в том, что вы не в курсе, что такое `sender`. А это по сути текстбокс, вызвавший событие.

Заведите такой обработчик.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbx = (TextBox)sender;
    tbx.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    tbx.ToolTip = null;
}
```

Теперь всем текстбоксам в XAML назначаете этот обработчик. А дубликаты методов спокойно удаляете. Но опять же, лучше воспользоваться советом из самого начала этого ответа.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я максимально проглупил и даже не задумывался , что всем текстбоксам достаточно присвоить одно событие. Также прочитаю про ваш первый совет. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @Григорий вынести в отдельный файл тоже можно, обратите внимание на приписку `partial` у класса. Создаете в проекте новый .cs файл, пишете там так же `public partial class MainWindow : Window { ... }`, переносите методы туда, и готово. Но это тоже так себе решение, я его даже в ответе писать поэтому не стал.

Comment: Здесь в общем-то и команд нет. Вынести стили текстбоксов и кнопок с нужными стилевыми триггерами в отдельный ResourceDictionary, его импортировать в ресурсы окна. Будет работать даже без биндингов к модели.

Comment: @user11354240 оно понятно